# URL scheme for Settings/General/About/Certificate Trust Settings in iOS 10

Tags: ios, ios10, truststore

I spent a lot of time researching how to programmatically launch the Settings app and show the "Certificate Trust Settings".  I managed to programmatically launch the Settings app and show the About section with the following URL scheme:

let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=General&path=About")

However, I can't seem to find a way to get to the Trust Store section (one more level down).  I know for certain sections in Settings, a URL scheme can be built to drill down multiple levels (E.g. path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS).  So I experimented with various URLs (/TRUST_STORE, /CERTIFICATE_TRUST_SETTINGS, /CERTIFICATES, etc), but all failed to get to the Trust Store section directly.

Is this simply not achievable with the current version of iOS?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just want to share my recent discovery regarding the URL Scheme for accessing "Certificate Trust Settings".  It differs from language to language.  The root URL scheme is the same for General/About, however, Certificate Trust Setting must match the way Apple translated it in each language.  Use UTF-8 encoding for any special characters.  Hopefully this information will help somebody out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue and solved it by the following URL scheme (I tested it on iOS 10.3):

`"App-Prefs:root=General&path=About/Certificate%20Trust%20Settings"`

Comment: Thank you very much for that URL scheme!! It worked flawlessly for me in both the Simulator as well as actual device running iOS 10.3.

Comment: This no longer seems to work as of iOS 14. Have you found another URL?